# Share image On facebook in watchKit using the Social sdk

Tags: swift, watchkit

i want share the image on Facebook in iWatch kit now problem occur in one line need help

```
 if  SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeTwitter)       {         var twitterSheet:SLComposeViewController =      SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter)
            twitterSheet.setInitialText("Share on Twitter")
       self.presentViewController(twitterSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
```

Now problem in last line code the error is this  classname does not have a member name presentViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few issues here:

- WatchKit does not include the Social framework.
- `WKInterfaceController` does not include the method `presentViewController`.

You may want to look into using Handoff to share the item from the user's phone, instead.

Comment: u mean with the help of the Handoff function we upload the pic on Facebook right ?

Comment: Yes. Prompt the user to open the app on their phone using Handoff, then pass the objects to be shared to the phone. Initiate the sharing action on the phone.

Comment: Do a Google search for "iOS Handoff tutorial" and go from there. We're not here to hand you pre-made solutions. I've already pointed out why the code you posted wasn't working.